# How to improve number of request django on heroku can handle at a moment?

Tags: django, heroku, scaling

In my project, I use Django and heroku to deploy it. In Heroku, I use uWSGI server (with asynchronous mode), database is MySQL (on AWS RDS). I used 7 dyno for scaling django app

When I run stress test with 600 request/second, timeout is 30 second.
My server return > 50% with timeouts request.

Any ideas can help me improve my server performance?

Answer (score 0):

If your async setup is right (and this is the hardest part), well your only solution is adding more dynos. If you are not sure about django+async (or if you have not done any particular customization to make them work together), you have probably a screwed up setup (no concurrency at all).

Take in account that uWSGI async mode could means dozens of different setup (gevent, ugreen, callbacks, greenlets...), so some detail on your configuration could help.